# How can I change GNOME Terminal profile name in command line? (from 'Unnamed' to 'Default')

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, 20.10

I know how to change GNOME Terminal profile name using the GUI, but I would like to do the same using the command line (automated way). How can I do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

get the available profile names with below command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList list
```

to know the Default Profile, run below command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default
```

to get the Default Profle name, run the below command from above output

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/ visible-name
```

to rename the above, run below command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/ visible-name 'Default'
```

Like wise, if you have more than one Profile.. from the list command get the ids and you can change any profile name.

---

***Edit***

To simplify, you can have below script saved and run when you need it.

```
#!/bin/bash

id=$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default | tr -d "'")
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$id/ visible-name 'Default'
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Start `dconf-editor`. If it it not installed on your system, install it first.

Look in `org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:` and find the key for the desired profile.

From the command line, do:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:[key]/ visible-name [new_name]
```

Replace `[key]` with the key that you found in `dconf-editor` and `[new_name]` with the desired new profile name.